# Корректность подготовленного запроса

Tags: php, mysql

Корректен ли данный подготовленный запрос?
Имею 4 таблицы, в первой

```
News(id,id_owner,date_add,for)   
News_RUS(id,title,annon,text)  
News_ENG(id,title,annon,text)   
News_UKR(id,title,annon,text)
```

При удалении новости нужно удалить во всех таблицах, я решил сделать это так, но как-то слишком много кода...

```
public function delNews()
{
    $table = 'News';
    $stmt = $this->link->prepare("DELETE FROM $table WHERE $table.ID = ?");
    $stmt->bind_param('i',$_POST['id_news']);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->free_result();

    $table = 'News_RUS';
    $stmt = $this->link->prepare("DELETE FROM $table WHERE $table.ID = ?");
    $stmt->bind_param('i',$_POST['id_news']);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->free_result();

    $table = 'News_ENG';
    $stmt = $this->link->prepare("DELETE FROM $table WHERE $table.ID = ?");
    $stmt->bind_param('i',$_POST['id_news']);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->free_result();

    $table = 'News_UKR';
    $stmt = $this->link->prepare("DELETE FROM $table WHERE $table.ID = ?");
    $stmt->bind_param('i',$_POST['id_news']);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->free_result();
    }
```

Можно как-то сделать его меньше, или это норма?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$tables = array('News', 'News_RUS', 'News_ENG', 'News_UKR',);
foreach ($tables as $table) {
    $stmt = $this->link->prepare("DELETE FROM $table WHERE $table.ID = ?");
    $stmt->bind_param('i', $_POST['id_news']);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->free_result();
}
```

понятия не имею, что такое link, и сработает ли с 'i'.

Comment: link - это как бы указатель соединения БД с сервером, используется в mysqli,
link = new mysqli(host,user,password,db)
i - необходим, с цифрами или ярлыками не работает,
$stmt = $this->link->prepare("SELECT id FROM table LIMIT ?")
$stmt->bind_param(1,$count); - ошибка,
$stmt->bind_param('i',$count); - работает.